# Unity Cloud Build + Firebase 5.6.1 not working

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, unity3d-cloud-build

I recently upgraded firebase to the latest version (5.6.1). Local builds are working just fine, however I get errors when using Unity Cloud build with the updated files.

Some of my errors include:

Error (Not a directory) occured whilst enumerating /BUILD_PATH/mybuildpath/temp.XXXXXX20190408-5674-13zy4z1/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h

Many more like this

Referenced from FIRMessagingExtensionHelper.o:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error:

I've tried the solution found here:  I continue to get errors. I also turned off library caching, and tried clean builds and always yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr:**

in `Assets\Plugins\iOS\Firebase\libFirebaseCppMessaging.a.meta` change line:

`FrameworkDependencies:`

to

`FrameworkDependencies: UserNotifications;`

**long version:**

I encountered the exact same problem. You are missing Cocoapod dependencies. Unity cloud build does not support adding them to workspace (which is default) only to project. That is why local build work and cloud doesn't. Normally you can add dependencies in inspector (for example select Assets\Plugins\iOS\Firebase\libFirebaseCppMessaging.a file, with file selected you can choose dependencies in inspector). The missing framework is *UserNotifications framework*, and for some reason it is missing from the inspector options, so you have to add it manually (see tldr verion).

If the build still does not work, try to replicate failing build locally, to do it you can change ios resolver settings to "xcode project", and look for the name of the symbol that is missing in the build error message and google what framework it is from, and add that framework too.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This worked :) Additional note...initially I didn't see the 'FrameworkDependencies' field in meta. I clicked a checkmark to add an arbitrary framework by viewing the libFirebaseCppMessaging.a file, then it became visible on meta